# Where to put hardcoded strings?

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET page with combo box where are some items. It looks as follows:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cboExportToExcelChoice" EnableViewState="True" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="True">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Selected records" Value="Selected records" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="All records" Value="All records" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

As you can see Text and Value string is hard coded. Where can I put the string to not be hard coded?

Comment: how about assigning the value in code-behind?

Comment: There will be hard coded as well.

Comment: well, if you retrieve the non-hardcoded ones from a database, you could use a view instead of the real table and simply "UNION"fy those values onto the resultset. But as you need to handle the hardcoded ones still on the logic side, keep it that way

Comment: They're not from database. Just a strings that I should put somewhere and get them.

Comment: What exactly you mean by Hard Coded ? It's going to change everytime? Or You want to keep in a way that incase if you want to change anything in future you dont have to do deployment again?

Comment: This is my case: "Or You want to keep in a way that incase if you want to change anything in future you dont have to do deployment again?"

Comment: putting value in code-behind is hardcode? Are you sure? You can change the values in codes.

Comment: It should be variable in code instead of some concrete string.

Comment: In the end I used separated resource file with static class that contains hard coded strings. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text in a resource file and get the value in the code-behind.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)